# How to use URP Sample Buffer in custom function node in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I need to sample the source buffer `NormalWorld` from the `URP Sample Buffer` for a range of UVs. In order to make this easier, I want to iterate through the range of UVs in a `Custom Function Node`. My issue is that I do not know how to sample the `NormalWorld` in a `Custom Function Node`.

**For comparison here is how to do it with the Scene Depth, using the documentation code :**
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@5.6/manual/Scene-Depth-Node.html

```
void Unity_SceneDepth_Raw_float(float4 UV, out float Out) {
    Out = SHADERGRAPH_SAMPLE_SCENE_DEPTH(UV);
}
```

In a `Custom Function Node` :

```
void myCustomDepth_float(float2 uv, out float depth) {
    depth = SHADERGRAPH_SAMPLE_SCENE_DEPTH(uv);
}
```

[image: Scene Depth & Custom Function Node give same result]

**And now what is the equivalent code to replicate the same for URP Sample Buffer? :**

- Documentation missing for URP Sample Buffer.

In a `Custom Function Node` :

```
void myCustomNormalWorld_float4(float2 uv, out float4 normalWorld) {
    normalWorld = ...?
}
```

[image: Implementation Missing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the source code of the `Graphics` git repo of Unity and searched up the implementation of the `URP Sample Buffer`.

This led me to a file named `UniversalSampleBufferNode.cs` where we can find the following implementation :

```
case BufferType.NormalWorldSpace:
    s.AppendLine("return SHADERGRAPH_SAMPLE_SCENE_NORMAL(uv);");
    break;
case BufferType.MotionVectors:
    s.AppendLine("uint2 pixelCoords = uint2(uv * _ScreenSize.xy);");
    s.AppendLine($"return LOAD_TEXTURE2D_X_LOD(_MotionVectorTexture, pixelCoords, 0).xy;");
    break;
case BufferType.BlitSource:
    s.AppendLine("uint2 pixelCoords = uint2(uv * _ScreenSize.xy);");
    s.AppendLine($"return LOAD_TEXTURE2D_X_LOD(_BlitTexture, pixelCoords, 0);");
    break;
default:
    s.AppendLine("return 0.0;");
    break;
```

Each `case` represents one of the choices of the dropdown for the `URP Sample Buffer`.

**Solution for NormalWorld:**

```
void myCustomNormalWorld_float4(float2 uv, out float4 normalWorld) {
    normalWorld = SHADERGRAPH_SAMPLE_SCENE_NORMAL(uv);
}
```